# Decorating a decorator

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I tried to do some argument modification on a decorator which decorates a function.
The original code looks like

```py
@original_decorator(arg=some_object)
def calculate(a, b):
  # complex business logic
  raise Exception()
```

where `original_decorator` is responsible for exception handling.

What I want to achieve is to do some temporary modification on `some_object` and restore it's property after function returned.

And I've tried the following

```py
def replace_arg(arg, add_some_property):
    def decorator_wrapper(decorator_func):
        def decorator_inner(*decorator_args, **decorator_kwargs):
            def actual_wrapper(actual_func):
                def actual_inner(*actual_args, **actual_kwargs):
                    original = arg['func']
                    arg['func'] = add_some_property
                    decorator_kwargs['arg'] = arg
                    result = actual_func(*actual_args, **actual_kwargs)
                    arg['func'] = original
                    return result 
                return actual_inner
            return actual_wrapper
        return retry_inner
    return retry_wrapper
```

Also tried to place the modification logic in `decorator_inner`, but neither worked.

My Questions:

1. Is it possible to modify a decorator's argument?
2. If true, then how can I achieve it?